# Ember view rendered at the bottom of the DOM

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using Ember and my view is getting rendered at the very bottom of my HTML DOM, instead of inside my div element.
Here is my source code :

**index.html :**

```
<body>
  <div id="test">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{view Skills.RecommendedSkillsListView}}
    </script>
  </div>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="recommended_skills_list">
  <a href="#" {{action "b"}}>DO A NEW THING</a>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js :**

```
Skills = Ember.Application.create({});
Skills.RecommendedSkillsListView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'recommended_skills_list',
  b: function(v) {
      alert('new hello');
  }    
});
Skills.initialize();
```

**The rendered document :**

```
<body class="ember-application">
  <div id="test"></div>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  <div id="ember135" class="ember-view">
    <div id="ember140" class="ember-view">
      <a href="#" data-ember-action="1">DO A NEW THING</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: when using the same code with a previous version of ember (0.9.5) it works as expected

Answer (score 22):

Ah, it looks like it is 'appending your view' to the body which you have given the 'application' template name which Ember will look for. Why not try putting a div inside the body and then referencing this in the Ember.Application.create();?

## Ember.Router

```
Skills = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#test'
});
```

## View

```
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  <div id="ember135" class="ember-view">
    <div id="ember140" class="ember-view">
      <a href="#" data-ember-action="1">DO A NEW THING</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if I've missed the point ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this actually doesn't solve the real problem :/ see my comment to the previous answer !

Comment: Please help me by explaining the downvote (whoever downvoted) thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

You need to specify the element to render your application to using the `rootElement` ([docs here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement), related question: [Emberjs rootElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399577/emberjs-rootelement)) property of your application:

```
Skills = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: "#test"
});
```

Here is a working example: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/6p6XJ/321/)

**Rendered output from example:**

```
<body>
  <div id="test" class="ember-application">
    <div id="ember135" class="ember-view">
      <div id="ember140" class="ember-view">
        <a href="#" data-ember-action="1">DO A NEW THING</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution actually works in my example, but what if I had two div elements (#test and #test2) in which I would like to have one specific view rendered in each of the div elements ? Your solution just allows me to change the root, but doesn't really solve my problem. Have any idea ? (my code up here works perfectly with ember-1.0.pre.min.js)
Thanks for your time though !

Comment: @alxscms You should have all of your ember templates rendered under the single `rootElement` of your application, but you can use ember functionality to have complete flexibility over which elements are rendered where inside of your `rootElement`.  Here is an example of having 3 views rendered side by side (http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/fLBty/3/).  It is slightly out of date, so you will have to look at the current guides for how to do this in the current version of ember (http://emberjs.com/guides/).

Comment: I also solved it using this answer, but still no idea why it doesn't work.